# Need hint for the Exercise posed in the Tensorflow Convolution Neural Networks Tutorial

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

Below is the exercise question posed on this page https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html

> EXERCISE: The output of inference are un-normalized logits. Try
>   editing the network architecture to return normalized predictions
>   using tf.softmax().

In the spirit of the exercise, I want to know if I'm on the right-track (not looking for the coded-up answer).

Here's my proposed solution.

**Step 1**: The last layer (of the inference) in the example is a "softmax_linear", i.e., it simply does the *unnormalized* WX+b transformation. As stipulated, we apply the `tf.nn.softmax` operation with `softmax_linear` as input. This normalizes the output as probabilities on the range [0, 1].

**Step 2:** The next step is to modify the cross-entropy calculation in the loss-function. Since we already have normalized output, we need to replace the `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` operation with a plain `cross_entropy(normalized_softmax, labels)` function (that does not further normalize the output before calculating the loss). I believe this function is **not** available in the tensorflow library; it needs to be written.

That's it. Feedback is kindly solicited.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is more then sufficient if you insert the `tf.nn.softmax()` in `cifar10_eval.py` (and not in `cifar10.py`). For example:

```
logits = cifar10.inference(images)
normalized_logits = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(normalized_logits, labels, 1)
```